# When an instance variable of an object is highlighted in debug mode in eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, hover, cursor

it shows a list of all the instance variables in that object as oppose to the instance variable that you're highlighting. For example:

```
package nmelssx;

public class Cat {
int num1;
int num2;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    cat.num1 = 5;

    if (cat.num1 == 5) {
        // then do this
    }
}
}
```

when you put your mouse cursor over cat.num1 it shows the value of both cat.num1 AND cat.num2. While this isn't really a problem when you only have a few instance variables in your object, it becomes somewhat of a problem when you have over a dozen, and you ONLY want to know the value of the instance variable that your cursor is hovering over. Anyone know a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Place your cursor over num1 instead of cat. And you will see only the value against num1

Comment: it just shows the object name, the class it was made in, and the package name, but no values.

Comment: This is not true. Second thing, if you are at that particular breakpoint, you can select cat.num1 and then Ctrl+Shift+I that will evaluate the expression or function and will show you the output

Comment: this is what the highlight says Open Declaration int nmelssx.Cat.num1

Comment: But as you can see, there are no values.

Comment: first thing your code is not compile-able because there is so many syntax error

Comment: I already fixed the codes in my program, and updated the codes above. That's what the debugger is saying.

Comment: put one breakpoint at if condition and debug! when control will come to that line move pointer to cat object you will get values

Comment: It's saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

if you put cursor on Object while debugging and press shortcut key `ctrl+shift+i` or you are moving cursor only on object it will show all the instance variable's value inside that object, but if your not debugging and pointing cursor only then it will show object name with class name and properties.

if you want to check separately then move cursor to distinct variable , in your case it is `num1` or `num2` , but if you are accessing these in static method then these variable should be static then only you will get values on pointing. if your accessing in instance method then there it will show.

please debug below code

```
public class Cat{
static int num1;
int num2;

public static void main(String args[]){
Cat cat = new Cat();
num1 = 5;
cat.num2=6;
cat.display();

if(num1 == 5){
//then do this
}

}
public void display(){
    System.out.println(num2);
}
}
```

put breakpoint in 2 places first at if condition second in display method and check.

Comment: this is what the highlight says Open Declaration int nmelssx.Cat.num1

Comment: But as you can see, there are no values.

Comment: if you debug you will get same thing

Comment: It's saying the same thing.

Comment: I debugged it. It says num2 = 6 when you hover the mouse over it. But that's not what I'm wanting. I want it so if you hover over the num1 in cat.num1, it shows your value of cat.num1, instead of nothing. I know if you hover over the object cat instead, it'll show you all the instance variables inside the cat object, but that's not what I want. Is there a way to make it so if you hover over num1 in cat.num1 it shows you value of cat.num1 instead of nothing?

Comment: if it's not possible please let me know.

Comment: it only shows because its not object.variable. Its just variable. So basically object.variable doesnt work is what you are saying. So say that instead of saying it works,  because it doesnt.

Comment: if you are doing this.<variablename> in instance method then also it will show. @nmelssx